# Passing values in access through en empty form?

Tags: ms-access, report

I have a report where user is able to enter FROM and TO date. I pass these values to an empty form and pass them on to the report to filter. The thing I came across is when I do PRINT PREVIEW, and actually manually enter the values for FROM and TO, I see the complete report. However, if I open the aforementioned empty form, and type in the values there, and run the report it does not show any data. I made sure the values are correct. I ran individual queries, for FOR and it showed data, then I ran it ONLY for TO and it also worked, however when I try to run them both  as shown below, I see no results. The name of forms and Txt boxes I'm referencing are a 100% correct.

```
Between [Forms]![frmREPORT]![txtFrom] And [Forms]![frmREPORT]![txtTo]
```

In the Field I have the name of the Column TransactionDate, WHERE and the statement above is in CRITERIA

What could be the issue?

Comment: This could conceivably happen if the FROM and TO are the same date, or one date apart.  Try changing it to " >= [Forms]![frmREPORT]![txtFrom] And =< [Forms]![frmREPORT]![txtTo] " (without the quotes).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. After entering the "TO" date, I did not TAB OFF the texxtbox in the form. Once I did it, everything worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: Could you can mark your answer as correct so it doesn't show among the unsolved questions?